# 3 Dimensions / Repeated output in LLAMA 2 for Word embedding

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, llama

I'm trying to get output[0] in LLAMA 2 with AutoModelForCausalLM, in the code:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(features['input_ids'].to(device),features['attention_mask'].to(device),output_hidden_states=True)
cls_train = outputs[0]
aux = cls_train.to("cpu")
Y = database['label']
```

But output[0] has 3 dimensions and the chosen machine learning models (logistic regression, svm)  only use 2. Then, i did:

```
new_aux = []
for x in aux:
  new_aux.append(x[0])
vec = torch.stack(new_aux, dim=0)
```

To get just the two dimensions used in the model, but the resulting tensor is coming with the repeated values. What can I do?

PS: I tried using the last_hidden_state, but, apparently, this model does not have. The tokenizer didn't have the pad_token, so I did tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'}). I don't know if that influences it.

Comment: Have you tried printing out those objects in a notebook or using __dict__ to see attributes of the objects?

Comment: @transposeglobal Yes, that's when I realized they were repeated